# SSIS - how to transform a Recordset as a result of an "Execute SQL Task" into a List<string>

Tags: c#, sql, list, ssis, recordset

Having a result from "Execute SQL Task" step in an SSIS package, how to transform the result(RecordSet) into List  ?
(result of the sql script: 1 nvarchar column)

Step 1: "Execute SQL Task", 
         script: "select Name from MyTable", 
         ResultSet: "Full result set", mapped "0" to variable "User::Names"

Step 2: ?

Step 3: Using a variable "User::NameList" of type List containing all values selected in script from 1st line.

Comment: Could you [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28792306/edit) your question and add the relevant code you have? It's easier for readers to come up with an answer when there is some code to start with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public void Main()
    {
        var dt = new DataTable();

        new OleDbDataAdapter().Fill(dt, this.Dts.Variables["User::Names"].Value);

        var list = dt.Rows.OfType<DataRow>().Select(i => i[0].ToString()).ToList();

        this.Dts.Variables["User::NameList"].Value = list;

        this.Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }
```